# Summarising a Pivot Table by Month Groups

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a simple table with Monthly downloads data for the last 24 months. I want to build a simple Summary showing the following columns.

- Number of Downloads for last Month
- Downloads in the last 3 Months
- Downloads in the last 6 Months.
- Downloads in Last 6 Months (last year)
- Downloads in Last 3 Months (last year)
- Downloads in Last Month (last year)

I tried to group the data in the pivot table - but I can't seem to get it to work as Google Sheets doesn't allow overlapping Groups.

I tried using Calc fields - but again it doesn't seem to allow me to break it out by months.

Any Idea - how to do this or am I asking too much of Google Sheets?

Added a dummy set of data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qhuXf__hvJMZjXcugBZyiq_lZBqFNTTkCHEvh9rcUK0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: pls share a copy/dummy of your sheet

Comment: Thanks @player0 - added!

Comment: can you also include your desired output?

Comment: Added! Hope this is enough detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({$C$3:$O$5,$C$7:$O$9}), 
 "select Col2,Col3 
  where Col1>=date'"&TEXT(DATE(E13,1,1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col1< date'"&TEXT(DATE(E13,9,1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")), 
 "select Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5+Col6+Col7+Col8+Col9 
  label Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5+Col6+Col7+Col8+Col9''"),
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({$C$3:$O$5,$C$7:$O$9}), 
 "select Col2,Col3 
  where Col1>=date'"&TEXT(DATE(E13,9,1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col1< date'"&TEXT(DATE(E13+1,1,1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")), 
 "select Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5 
  label Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5''"),
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({$C$3:$O$5,$C$7:$O$9}), 
 "select Col2,Col3 
  where Col1>=date'"&TEXT(DATE(E13,12,1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col1< date'"&TEXT(DATE(E13+1,1,1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")), 
 "select Col2")}
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n9Bbg0EySXT0UabW0-BHsA_uB5ecgUb-8I_99qcBVpc/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: Wow - thats amazing - I will have a look at how you did that.  Can you share any explanation?

Comment: its just 3 simple queries put in `{}` - virtual array. each query is predetermined to look for a certain date period and all is based on the year cell (in case you want to create dropdown menu and select summary for chosen year) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7qc1.png